# Lossless Video Compression Pipeline

Tags: reference-request, data-compression, video

The only paper I can find about an implementation of a lossless video codec is an [article by Michael Niedermayer](http://www.ffmpeg.org/~michael/ffv1.html) which explains the FF1V compression pipeline.

I'm wondering if anyone else has found any articles similar to this. I've looked on IEEE and ACM and their articles mostly focus on one algorithm that's part of a compression pipeline.